# Error : Expected statement 800A0400 in my VBScript

Tags: vbscript

Below is the start of a automation script ive been working on. The script opens IE, Goes to a URL and enters the logon credentials. I Then need to check if a image is loaded ("/codaprod/images/portal.jpg")... I really dont know much and ive been mainly picking at bits from here and there. The script work fine untill i add the below bit of code to the end.

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
sub loadImage()
  msgbox "Image is loaded"
end sub
</script>

<img src="/codaprod/images/portal.jpg" onload="loadImage">
```

Is there something wrong with this snippit of code or am i missing something in my original code?

Below is the full VBScript im using.

```
strURL="https://WEBADDRESS.com/codaprod/servlet/HTMLCompiler?app=com.coda.common.esi.framework.apps.Logon" 

strUser="USERNAME" 

strPass="PASSWORD" 


 Set oIE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application","IE_")  
 Timeout=20 'seconds  
 oIE.visible=1 : BeginTimer = Timer  
 oIE.Navigate strURL  
 i=0 : bElementsLoaded=false  
 Set CODA_Element_1 = Nothing
 Do While (oIE.ReadyState<>4 Or Not(bElementsLoaded)) And i < Timeout  
    WScript.Sleep(1000):i=i+1  
    On Error Resume Next 

      Set CODA_Element_1 = oIE.Document.getElementById("user")
      Set CODA_Element_2 = oIE.Document.getElementById("password")
      Set CODA_Element_3 = oIE.Document.getElementById("next")


       If     (Not(CODA_Element_1 is Nothing)) Then  

        bElementsLoaded=true  

       End If 

    On Error Goto 0  

 Loop 

CODA_Element_1.value=strUser 
CODA_Element_2.value=strPass 
CODA_Element_3.Click()  

wscript.sleep 3000

<script type="text/vbscript">
sub loadImage()
  msgbox "Image is loaded"
end sub
</script>

<img src="/codaprod/images/portal.jpg" onload="loadImage">
```

Thanks for reading and please feel free to point out any hints, tips that you have.
Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Those are HTML tags `<script>` etc., and don't belong in your script-file.

If you want to check if the image is loaded then you need to use code similar to your earlier code, that repeatedly tries to reference the img-element in the page. If this img doesn't have an id then it becomes a little more complicated.

You might, for example, use `getElementsByTagName("IMG")` to obtain the collection of all the images. If you know it is the third one then:

```
getElementsByTagName("IMG")[2]
```

would (in JavaScript) obtain a reference to it. I don't know what adjustments this code might need to work in VBScript, maybe round brackets (2). It may, in fact, be indexes as (3) in VBScript, as many VBS collections are indexed from 1, rather than 0. [Edited: I believe `getElementsByTagName` is still zero-indexed in VBS.]

If you don't know which specific IMG element contains this image, then you'll need to loop through the collection (of IMG tags, as above) checking its `src` attribute using `getAttribute()`. `querySelector` is a *possible* alternative to obtaining the element with this src-attribute.

Comment: Hi Firstly Thanks for taking the time to reply :)  I think i understand what you mean. I also have this piece of code that dosnt show any errors but i also says that the image is not loaded. Any ides?  Set imgs = oIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("IMG") 
 For i = 0 to imgs.length - 1 
    If imgs(i).src = "/codaprod/images/portal.jpg" then 
       imgFound = True 
   End if 
 Next 
 If imgFound then 
    wscript.echo "Image found" 
 else 
    wscript.echo "Image Not found" 
 End If

Comment: Within the loop echo out each `src`; it may be that these are in a slightly different format than "/folder/images/portal.jpg".

Comment: Sorry i dont understand? I can see in the source code that the image is /codaprod/images/portal.jpg. What do you mean by in a slightly differant format? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just echo out the src's? It is the easiest way to check. I mean, for example, that it might start with './' or drop the first back-slash, or appear with the full (absolute) path.

Comment: ive already tried dropping the / and using the full absolute path but it still just comes back with image not found. When you say to echo out the Src's can you please give a example of code? I really am a beginner and really do appriciate your help lol Thanks!

Comment: Sorry cant get it to work. Think i might be in for a long night :( Thanks for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, try taking away your original addition and use this:

```
If GetImgStatus("/codaprod/images/portal.jpg", oIE) = true Then
MsgBox("Image is loaded")
End If



Function GetImgStatus(source, ie)
Dim i

For Each i in ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")
If i.src = source Then
GetImgBySource = i.complete
End If

End Function
```

Script tags are used when you're running script from within an HTML document.

Cheers,  LC

Comment: Hi, When i use this i get the error expected statement? Thanks for your help ive been stuck on this for weeks lol